# How to include tar.gz file in Python package?

Tags: python, tar

I have a package (here called `magic`) which has a directory structure as follows:

```
magic/
  magic/
    __init__.py
    load_services.py
    services/
      rabbit_out_of_hat.tar.gz
  setup.py
```

My `setup.py` file looks like this:

```py
# setup.py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='magic',
    package=setuptools.find_packages(),
    # ...
)
```

I would like `load_services.py` to look something like the following, where in short, a function is used to copy the relevant `tar.gz` to the current directory and unzip it:

```py
# load_services.py
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import tarfile

def load_service(name: str):
   fname = f'{name}.tar.gz'
   shutil.copy(Path('/path/to/services/folder') / fname, Path('.'))
   tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:gz")
   tar.extractall()     
   tar.close()
```

So the package would be used in the following way:

```
# random script
import magic

# load rabbit_out_of_hat service
magic.load_service('rabbit_out_of_hat')

# do something with service
# ...
```

My question is:

1. How do I include the `services` folder with the `tar.gz` files in the package when it is installed
2. What would the `'/path/to/services/folder'` by in the `load_services.py` file?
3. Are there any size limitations when following this structure and uploading to PyPI?

Comment: Does [this](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) help?

Comment: Yes that looks good - there seem to be a few different options so it would be good to see an actual solution from an experienced user